# Ninject and ChildKernel in MVC3 project: "Error loading Ninject component ICache"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm using Ninject (3.0) in my ASP.Net MVC3 project. At some point of request handling I want to execute some tasks.

I'm using session-per-request pattern but don't want these tasks to share the same Session as current Request has. So, I thought, ChildKernels could help me with this issue. I was going to create another binding for ISession in child kernel, but started with that:

```
var child = new Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel.ChildKernel(NinjectMVC3.Kernel);
child.Dispose();
```

If I execute the code like that during request I get `Error loading Ninject component ICache` exception *at the end of my request* (not at `.Dispose()` call). If I remove `child.Dispose()` everything is fine.

So, am I choosing the right way to go with ChildKernel? Is it safe to use the child kernels without explicitly disposing them? Why Ninject throws at the request end if I dispose the child kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is thrown because you load all the modules from the extensions into the child kernel. Creating the kernel with LoadExtensions=false would fix that problem. But this is not the solution in your case.

The intention of the ChildKernel isn't really for different scoping. You would need to register everything for the tasks on that child kernel. Just the session won't be enough. Adding just a conditional binding for the session is far the better option.

Comment: Thanks, I was just used to ChildContainer in Unity, so I thought about using ChildKernel the same way :) At the moment ChildContainer feels a little bit more transparent for me, I'll try to get used with conditional bindings :)