# Error loading Ninject component ICache

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

I am using ninject in an asp.net web api project and have started receiving this intermittent ninject error:

"**Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.**"

I'm using:

- Ninject 3.0.1.10
- Ninject.MVC3 3.0.0.6
- Ninject.Web.Common 3.0.0.7

They are all brought into my project with NuGet I load my Modules in IocConfig.RegisterIoc and have made no other changes or tweaks.

It may be unrelated but the problem  started occurring at around the same time as I started injecting IKernel into one of my constructors.  I didn't set up a binding for this having read about the "special resolver".

I have read through a number of similar questions on here:

[Ninject + "Error loading Ninject component ICache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134630/ninject-error-loading-ninject-component-icache)

[Ninject and ChildKernel in MVC3 project: "Error loading Ninject component ICache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958445/ninject-and-childkernel-in-mvc3-project-error-loading-ninject-component-icache)

[Randomly-Occurring Ninject Exception: "Error loading Ninject component ICache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732645/randomly-occurring-ninject-exception-error-loading-ninject-component-icache)

Although in each of these cases the OP has the same error as me the solution is not appropriate - I am not creating child kernels and I'm not using the bugged version of ninject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution and thought I would share.

The problem was that I was Using Ninject.MVC3 which seems to be wrong package for Web-API.

Instead I need to use Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC package as described by this post:

http://www.eyecatch.no/blog/2012/06/using-ninject-with-webapi-rc/

Steps I followed for a fix are

- Uninstalled Ninject.MVC3 and Ninject.Web.Common
- delete all of the ninject files from the App_Start folder.
- install Ninject.Web.Common and Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC from nuget
- Load my modules in NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices()