# Error loading Ninject component ICache with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 2.2.0

Tags: ninject, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, ninject.web.mvc

With the recent update of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.* to 2.2.0, NInject is not working properly anymore.

I get the following error (not finding any services registered in NInject)

> Error loading Ninject component ICache
>   No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Everything used to work just fine with the version 2.1.0. Could it be a bug introduced in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity? Or a remnant bug from NInject (if so, which package?)

Really similar to [Error loading Ninject component ICache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757142/error-loading-ninject-component-icache), but this just started happening since version 2.2.0

I use latest of all NInject on NuGet.

- NInject 3.2.2.0
- Ninject.MVC3 3.2.1.0
- Ninject.Web.Common 3.2.3.0
- Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost 3.2.3.0
- Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost 3.2.3.0